# MySQL Dead Lock on Delete Issue

Tags: mysql, innodb, deadlock

I have recently updated my production code with the new query that is supposed to clean up orphaned records. It runs within the transaction as the last step.
And, as a result, I am seeing occasional dead lock exceptions coming from MySQL:

```
org.springframework.dao.DeadlockLoserDataAccessException: PreparedStatementCallback;
SQL [
DELETE ts FROM topic_subscriptions AS ts LEFT JOIN 
endpoint_to_topic_subscription_associations AS ctsa 
ON ts.id=topic_subscription_id WHERE ctsa.topic_subscription_id IS NULL
]; (conn=2699877) Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction; nested exception is java.sql.SQLTransactionRollbackException: (conn=2699877) Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
```

Here are the DDLs for the 2 tables in question:

```
CREATE TABLE `topic_subscriptions` (
  `id` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  `org_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `topic_subscription` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `virtual_broker_id` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_ts_vbid_on_topic_subscriptions` (`topic_subscription`,`virtual_broker_id`),
  KEY `FK_topic_subscriptions_references_organizations_table` (`org_id`),
  KEY `FK_topic_subs_refs_virtual_brokers_table` (`virtual_broker_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_topic_subs_refs_virtual_brokers_table` FOREIGN KEY (`virtual_broker_id`) REFERENCES `virtual_brokers` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_topic_subscriptions_references_organizations_table` FOREIGN KEY (`org_id`) REFERENCES `organizations` (`org_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `endpoint_to_topic_subscription_associations` (
  `endpoint_id` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  `topic_subscription_id` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  `org_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`endpoint_id`,`topic_subscription_id`),
  KEY `FK_endpoint_to_topic_subscription_ref_org_tbl` (`org_id`),
  KEY `FK_endpoint_to_topic_subscription_ref_topic_subscriptions_tbl` (`topic_subscription_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_endpoint_to_topic_subscription_ref_endpoints` FOREIGN KEY (`endpoint_id`) REFERENCES `endpoints` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_endpoint_to_topic_subscription_ref_org_tbl` FOREIGN KEY (`org_id`) REFERENCES `organizations` (`org_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_endpoint_to_topic_subscription_ref_topic_subscriptions_tbl` FOREIGN KEY (`topic_subscription_id`) REFERENCES `topic_subscriptions` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

As you can see I am not doing any explicit locking here or `SELECT FOR UPDATE` in the query above. I do use `SELECT FOR UPDATE` mechanism in other transactions but it doesn't involve the mentioned tables directly.

Also, the default isolation level is `REPEATABLE_READ`.

Please help me understand the issue here.
Thanks!

==================UPDATE===================

```
------------------------
LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
------------------------
2021-04-13 08:34:28 0x2b2a3b191700
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 22501318, ACTIVE 0 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 2, locked 2
LOCK WAIT 24 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 881 row lock(s), undo log entries 8
MySQL thread id 2699877, OS thread handle 47459092735744, query id 13624170039 172.25.150.126 [db_name] Sending data
DELETE ts FROM topic_subscriptions AS ts LEFT JOIN endpoint_to_topic_subscription_associations AS ctsa ON ts.id=topic_subscription_id WHERE ctsa.topic_subscription_id IS NULL
*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 824 page no 5 n bits 568 index FK_endpoint_to_topic_subscription_ref_topic_subscriptions_tbl of table [db_name].`endpoint_to_topic_subscription_associations` trx id 22501318 lock mode S waiting
Record lock, heap no 427 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 2; compact format; info bits 32
 0: len 12; hex 32326672616638696f746770; asc 22fraf8iotgp;;
 1: len 11; hex 7638313876336d30307566; asc v818v3m00uf;;

*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 22501319, ACTIVE 0 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 2, locked 2
24 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 21 row lock(s), undo log entries 13
MySQL thread id 2699872, OS thread handle 47460380120832, query id 13624170054 172.25.150.126 [db_name] Sending data
DELETE ts FROM topic_subscriptions AS ts LEFT JOIN endpoint_to_topic_subscription_associations AS ctsa ON ts.id=topic_subscription_id WHERE ctsa.topic_subscription_id IS NULL
*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 824 page no 5 n bits 568 index FK_endpoint_to_topic_subscription_ref_topic_subscriptions_tbl of table [db_name].`endpoint_to_topic_subscription_associations` trx id 22501319 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap
Record lock, heap no 427 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 2; compact format; info bits 32
 0: len 12; hex 32326672616638696f746770; asc 22fraf8iotgp;;
 1: len 11; hex 7638313876336d30307566; asc v818v3m00uf;;

*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 861 page no 5 n bits 192 index PRIMARY of table [db_name].`topic_subscriptions` trx id 22501319 lock_mode X waiting
Record lock, heap no 103 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 6; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 12; hex 323266723836636b67376572; asc 22fr86ckg7er;;
 1: len 6; hex 0000015694e6; asc    V  ;;
 2: len 7; hex e200000231014f; asc     1 O;;
 3: len 7; hex 6d616173646576; asc maasdev;;
 4: len 18; hex 746f706c6576656c2f6e6578746c6576656c; asc toplevel/nextlevel;;
 5: len 12; hex 323266723836636b67373666; asc 22fr86ckg76f;;

*** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those two `DELETEs` are each doing a full table scan looking for certain rows to delete.  Redundant.  One will be automatically killed (by InnoDB); the other will to the task assigned.

Just looking at those Deletes, I see two issues --

- Potentially inefficient way to delete rows.  If this is a big table, let's talk about ways to walk through it in chunks.
- Unnecessarily repeating the command from separate connections.  Have only one task in the background doing the delete.  When it finishes, it starts over.
- Perhaps a need for code elsewhere to prevent the need for the delete.  When the row is deleted from `ctsa`, delete the corresponding row from `ts`.
- Toss the deletes.  Check the other code -- perhaps it works correctly even when there is a missing row from `ctsa`.  If not, maybe a minor change will make it work 'correctly'.

Which of those would you like to discuss further?

If you don't need the Deletes to be performed *immediately*, you could have a background task that continually does such Deletes -- Delete some rows, sleep a few seconds, loop.  If the table is, say, bigger than 100 rows, search for rows to delete in chunks.  See http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig#deleting_in_chunks

Comment: Here is how I am thinking to do:

I want to break this query into 2 phases: 
1. I want to detect all topic subscription ids that have no reference in the association table.
2. Remove entries with given ids.

Do you think that this will not longer pose a risk of the dead lock? 
Thanks.

Comment: @IhorM. - Probably no better.

Comment: What do you exactly mean when you say that breaking the deletion query into 2 phases would probably be no better. Shouldn't that void the risk of deadlocks, since the deletion would now be happening by PKs as opposed to full table scans? Or were you concerned more from a performance/optimization perspective? Please shed some light.

Comment: @IhorM. - Perhaps you are right.  There will still be a full table scan in the Select, but that is not likely to cause a deadlock.  And I don't think you need `FOR UPDATE`, nor does the `SELECT` have to be inside the `BEGIN..COMMIT` transaction.  At worst, the Delete might try to delete some rows that are already gone.  Give it a try.